# Row Level Dynamic Data Masking in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, masking, data-masking

I need to mask a `email` column based on `IsMaskingNeeded` column in the `Employee` table. If the IsMaskingNeeded property is true then Only I need to mask the email column . If the value in IsMaskingNeeded column is false I need to get the unmasked value. The masked Value should be 'Information Withheld'. Is there anyway I can do this custom conditional Row level Dynamic masking with sql server?

Comment: That isn't Data Masking. But this sounds like you could just achieve this with a `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Larnu How I can achieve this using case?

Comment: I suggest having a go first, and if you fail, then posting your attempt. This would be very simple to achieve with `CASE`. If you don't know how to use a `CASE`, search for its documentation.